# Xubuntu Linux - Why doesn't my localhost direct me to my virtual host site?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache

I am setting up a virtual host on my linux machine, I followed all the steps and guides, but I do not go to my site for some reason. I have LAMP installed and apache, mysql, php is all working. I have a database setup on phpmyadmin and imported a database, but for some reason I cannot get my IP directed to my site! Its literally the last step I need so I can start working on my project.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   cbirc.com

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@cbirc.com
    ServerName cbirc.com
    ServerAlias www.cbirc.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cbirc
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I missing here???

Comment: Did you restart your services?

Comment: I did restart them, but it only pulls up a normal website, rather than my local host website I want it to pull up. I don't understand why its not working.

Comment: to avoid dns clashes and other pokey problems, its a good idea to use .local or .dev or somesuch for any locally hosted sites on your machine. This also avoids the issue of looking at the wrong site when youre developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check bunch of stuff:

Is apache running

```
sudo service apache2 status
```

Afterwards, test it with

```
netstat -na | grep 80
ping cbirc.com
```

Was  website enabled by issuing following command?

```
sudo a2ensite cbirc 
file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/cbirc.conf  (or some similar name it that folder)
```

Does www-data group and user (apache) has read-execute access on web content folder

```
ln -l /var/www/cbirc
```

If not, change it like this

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/cbirc
sudo chmod -R ug+rx /var/www/cbirc
```

Before issuing request in browser (to eliminate browser cache or security issues), do it with curl or wget

```
wget http://cbirc.com/
curl -v http://cbirc.com/
```

And look for errors in logifile

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Please refer to [my debian cheetsheat](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1ehLgBv2LtX_fPpUk7qIcdv39t56zUmcRTxnE_HU15mE) for further help

Comment: Apparently the problem was I didn't do a browser clear cache, but your answer was helpful so I marked it as best :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, run 'dig' or 'host' on cbirc.com

Although it is in your /etc/hosts , resolv.conf may prioritise nameservers above your hosts file.

If it is pointing to your localhost, then check the you have enabled the site - a2ensite [name of vhost conf file without the .conf extention] - check by looking in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled for a symbolic link to the sites-available directory.